# How to change Fax to mobileno and phone no to contact no in magento backeng ->manage customer ->address?

Tags: magento

In my magento back end under admin ->manage customer how can I change Lable Fax  to mobileno and phone no to  contact no in magento backeng ->manage customer ->address??

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code at the very bottom of Magento's index.php file and run it once for each attribute by accessing your website:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_address_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter('attribute_code')->getFirstItem();
$attribute->setFrontendLabel('New Label')->save();
```

Don't forget to delete the code after you finish the task.